# How to implement jQuery slider with images?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, asp.net-mvc-4

I am working on moving a site away from JOOMLA and replicating it using MVC 4.0. One part of the homepage includes a small slider that every three seconds 'slides' Sponsor logos. While researching, I found several excellent jQuery sliders, but none that offered the ability to have multiple images included in the slider (would have to manually create, say 5 sponsor logos, into one image). This would be viable, but in the future I want members to be able to upload their logos to a designated folder.

I came across the following JSFIDDLE which is VERY similar to what I am after: [JSFIDDLE 643](http://jsfiddle.net/qZNnk/643/)

[image]

Being new to jQuery however, I seem to be having issues using  in place of the colored  tags.

[image]

All the sponsors are stacked on top of each other instead of sliding as I desire. I believe this might be me failing to implement the jQuery correctly...?

Here is my code if anyone has any ideas? There in the end will be close to 40 sponsors. Each logo will be a width of 150px, and I'm trying to show 5 per visible area (the JSFIDDLE has 3 squares).

**Index.cshtml**

```
    ViewBag.Title = "Index";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}

@Scripts.Render("~/Scripts/jquery-1.9.1.min.js")
@Scripts.Render("~/Scripts/jquery.lbslider.js")

<script type="text/javascript">
 $(document).ready(function () {
      $('#slider').lbSlider({
           leftBtn: '#arrow-left', // left control selector
           rightBtn: '#arrow-right', // right control selector
           visible: 3, // visible elements quantity
           autoPlay: true, // autoscroll flag (default: false)
           autoPlayDelay: 5 // delay of autoscroll in seconds (default: 10)
      });
 });
</script>

                                                                 <h3>Our Valued Sponsors</h3>

<div class="slider-wrap">
     <div class="slider">
         <ul>
             <li>
                 <span><img src="1" alt="" /></span>
             </li>
             <li>
                 <span><img src="2" alt="" /></span>
             </li>
             <li>
                 <span><img src="3" alt="" /></span>
             </li>
             <li>
                 <span><img src="4" alt="" /></span>
             </li>
             <li>
                 <span><img src="5" alt="" /></span>
             </li>
             <li>
                 <span><img src="6" alt="" /></span>
             </li>
             <li>
                 <span><img src="7" alt="" /></span>
             </li>
             <li>
                 <span><img src=8" alt="" /></span>
             </li>
             <li>
                 <span><img src="9" alt="" /></span>
             </li>
             <li>
                 <span><img src="10" alt="" /></span>
             </li>
        </ul>
     </div>
     <a href="#" class="slider-arrow sa-left">&lt;</a>
     <a href="#" class="slider-arrow sa-right">&gt;</a>
</div>
```

**Site.css**

```
    .slider-wrap 
{
     position: relative;
     margin: 50px auto; 
     width: 950px;
}
.slider {
    position: relative;
    width: 890px;
    margin: auto;
    border: 5px solid black;
}
ul {
    margin: 0;
    padding:0;
}
ul li {
    list-style: none;
    text-align: center;
}
ul li span img {
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: middle;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    background: black;
}

     ul li img {
          width: 150px;
          height: auto;
     }

.slider-arrow {
    position: absolute;
    top: 40px;
    width: 20px;
    height: 20px;
    background: black;
    color: #fff;
    text-align: center;
    text-decoration: none;
    border-radius: 50%;
}

.sa-left {left: 10px;}
.sa-right {right: 10px;}
```

**jquery.lbslider.js**

```
(function ($) {
     $.fn.lbSlider = function (options) {
          var options = $.extend({
               leftBtn: '.leftBtn',
               rightBtn: '.rightBtn',
               visible: 3,
               autoPlay: false,  // true or false
               autoPlayDelay: 10  // delay in seconds
          }, options);
          var make = function () {
               $(this).css('overflow', 'hidden');

               var thisWidth = $(this).width();
               var mod = thisWidth % options.visible;
               if (mod) {
                    $(this).width(thisWidth - mod); // to prevent bugs while scrolling to the end of slider
               }

               var el = $(this).children('ul');
               el.css({
                    position: 'relative',
                    left: '0'
               });
               var leftBtn = $(options.leftBtn), rightBtn = $(options.rightBtn);

               var sliderFirst = el.children('li').slice(0, options.visible);
               var tmp = '';
               sliderFirst.each(function () {
                    tmp = tmp + '<li>' + $(this).html() + '</li>';
               });
               sliderFirst = tmp;
               var sliderLast = el.children('li').slice(-options.visible);
               tmp = '';
               sliderLast.each(function () {
                    tmp = tmp + '<li>' + $(this).html() + '</li>';
               });
               sliderLast = tmp;

               var elRealQuant = el.children('li').length;
               el.append(sliderFirst);
               el.prepend(sliderLast);
               var elWidth = el.width() / options.visible;
               el.children('li').css({
                    float: 'left',
                    width: elWidth
               });
               var elQuant = el.children('li').length;
               el.width(elWidth * elQuant);
               el.css('left', '-' + elWidth * options.visible + 'px');

               function disableButtons() {
                    leftBtn.addClass('inactive');
                    rightBtn.addClass('inactive');
               }
               function enableButtons() {
                    leftBtn.removeClass('inactive');
                    rightBtn.removeClass('inactive');
               }

               leftBtn.click(function (event) {
                    event.preventDefault();
                    if (!$(this).hasClass('inactive')) {
                         disableButtons();
                         el.animate({ left: '+=' + elWidth + 'px' }, 300,
                             function () {
                                  if ($(this).css('left') == '0px') { $(this).css('left', '-' + elWidth * elRealQuant + 'px'); }
                                  enableButtons();
                             }
                         );
                    }
                    return false;
               });

               rightBtn.click(function (event) {
                    event.preventDefault();
                    if (!$(this).hasClass('inactive')) {
                         disableButtons();
                         el.animate({ left: '-=' + elWidth + 'px' }, 300,
                             function () {
                                  if ($(this).css('left') == '-' + (elWidth * (options.visible + elRealQuant)) + 'px') { $(this).css('left', '-' + elWidth * options.visible + 'px'); }
                                  enableButtons();
                             }
                         );
                    }
                    return false;
               });

               if (options.autoPlay) {
                    function aPlay() {
                         rightBtn.click();
                         delId = setTimeout(aPlay, options.autoPlayDelay * 1000);
                    }
                    var delId = setTimeout(aPlay, options.autoPlayDelay * 1000);
                    el.hover(
                        function () {
                             clearTimeout(delId);
                        },
                        function () {
                             delId = setTimeout(aPlay, options.autoPlayDelay * 1000);
                        }
                    );
               }
          };
          return this.each(make);
     };
})(jQuery);
```

**EDIT**: Thanks to everyone who commented. I ended up doing some slight modification and going with the Twitter Bootstrap - Carousel.js.

Comment: You have a reference to `jQuery`, but where is your reference to the slider plugin?

Comment: @AshishKumar - That was the Fiddle he found, but in his example code it doesn't mention the plugin anywhere.

Comment: Sorry Nick, you are right. This is possibly because of no definition of **slider** after jquery.

Comment: You guys were right. I now have included the jquery.lbslider.js file, but still no luck getting it to work. When I check the Chrome console, it still says `Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'lbSlider'`?